# Adapt package.json after new Angular 2 minor version was released

Tags: angular

This is how the package.json of my Angular 2 app looks recently:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~2.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.2.0",
"@angular/core": "~2.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "~2.2.0",
"@angular/http": "~2.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.0",
"@angular/router": "~3.2.0",
"@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.0",
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.5",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"systemjs": "0.19.40",
"zone.js": "^0.6.25",
"primeng": "^1.0.1",
"ng2-webstorage": "1.4.1"
```

As we know, Angular 2 got [updated](http://angularjs.blogspot.de/2016/12/angular-230-now-available.html) to minor version 2.3 lately.

Now I am wondering how to adjust my dependencies accordingly. For instance, just replacing all 2.2.0 by 2.3.0 related to @angular/... does not work.

So how do I figure out which of the dependencies can be updated to 2.3 and which ones not?

---

After running *npm outdated* I adjusted my package.json as follows:

```
"@angular/common": "~2.3.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.3.0",
"@angular/core": "~2.3.0",
"@angular/forms": "~2.3.0",
"@angular/http": "~2.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.3.0",
"@angular/router": "~3.3.0",
"@angular/upgrade": "~2.3.0",
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.0",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
"rxjs": "5.0.1",
"systemjs": "0.19.41",
"zone.js": "^0.7.2",
"primeng": "^1.0.1",
"ng2-webstorage": "1.4.1"
```

However, during *npm install* I receive these message:

npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency tslint@~4.0.0 included from codelyzer will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "update"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package rxjs@5.0.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/core@2.3.0 wants rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/http@2.3.0 wants rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.3.0 wants rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular-in-memory-web-api@0.2.0 wants rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.20 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12

Any hints what is wrong here?

Comment: run `npm outdated` in terminal to check packages for updates

Comment: I did that and updated my package.json accordingly. See initial post above. Still I am receiving error messages

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean, it does not work? All `@angular` packages should be updated to `2.3.0` and `@router` to `3.3.0`. When a new version is released all packages are updated.

On the other hands, you should also update your `rxjs` and `zone.js` package, `5.0.0-rc.4` and `0.7.1` respectively

Comment: I did that and am still receiving error messages. Any pointers?

Comment: Run another `npm update`. You will see a lot less errors. You have to wait for codelyzer to update their package dependencies to not have errors any more. Nevertheless, if your code runs fine, you can safely ignore these errors

Comment: I still see the error messages mentioned above in my initial post. Are you sure I can safely ignore them?

Comment: Yes, except the `rxjs` warning. You should use `5.0.0-rc.4` and not `5.0.1`. Angular2 strongly depends on both rxjs and zone.js, so be sure to always keep this at the recommend version

Comment: Ok I adjusted rxjs and now it looks better. I still get this:
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.20 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.20 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.6.23 but none was installed.

Any pointers how to resolve this? Might be that I cannot influence it...

Comment: @Emdee you should delete `angular2-in-memory-web-api` and install `angular-in-memory-web-api@0.2.0` (notice the name difference) But depending on your testing preference, you probably won't need this package anyways

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update update angular2 package just run: **npm update angular2 --save**

Another solution would be to install this package: **[npm install -g npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)** and then run: 
**ncu -u** to rewrite your package.json file.